# Regex Match containing string between 2 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string in an HTTP page between `><`.

I'm having trouble with the first `>` as it also matches subsequent chars. eg. in this example

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="-logo js-gps-track"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:false, location:3, destination:8})">
                        <span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>
                    </a>
```

I would only want to match `Stack Overflow`. I've currently got `\>([^\>].*Stack Overflow.*)\<`
but that matches everything after the first `>` ie

```
><span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow<
```

Any help would be great

Comment: The best tip in this case: don't use regex at all. If it isn't an actual node, parse it as such, get the `<span>` and then its `.textContent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd probably be more elegant to use DOMParser, and take the `textContent` of `.-img._glyph`:

```js
const str = `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="-logo js-gps-track"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:false, location:3, destination:8})">
                        <span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>
                    </a>`;
console.log(
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').querySelector('.-img._glyph').textContent
);
```

If you *had* to use regex, instead of repeating `.` (which matches anything), repeat `[^<>]` (which matches anything which isn't a `<` or `>`) on either side of the `Stack Overflow` part, while looking ahead and behind for `<` and `>`:

[`(?<=>)[^<>]*Stack Overflow[^<>]*(?=<)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ytonyj/1)

(If you can't use lookbehind, match the initial `>` and capture everything afterwards, then extract the capture group)

Comment: thanks but for various reasons I need to use regex. Its also not entirely certain the source will be HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [lookbehind and lookahead assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), as in this regex: `(?<=>)Stack Overflow(?=<)`

```js
const text = `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="-logo js-gps-track"
                        data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:false, location:3, destination:8})">
                        <span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>
                    </a>`;
const regex = /(?<=>)Stack Overflow(?=<)/g;
const found = text.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```